# Regex Between Brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
<random stuff between><random stuff between><random stuff between><random stuff between>
```

I already can match this string using this Regex Pattern :

```
  if (Regex.IsMatch(arg, "^(<.+>){4}$"))
                return true;
```

But How can I get the content between the brackets, by also using Regex?

Comment: What is the expected output? 4 `random stuff between` substrings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var source = "<abc><def><g><hij>";
var pattern = new Regex("<(?<content>[^>]+)>");

var content = pattern.Matches(source).Cast<Match>().Select(m => 
  m.Groups["content"].Value).ToArray();
```

**EDIT** If you need  exactly 4 groups you can use this code (from @C Perkins comment):

```
var pattern = new Regex("^(<(?<content>[^>]+)>){4}$");
var content2 = pattern.Match(source).Groups["content"].Captures
                      .Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Some important differences here that should be noted, this is not anchored and not restricted to 4 repeats like the original. But if you use the qualifier (`{4}`) then the only group extracted will be the last one. The alternative is to explicitly repeat the pattern 4 times.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant! :)

Comment: @MattBurland you are right, thank you. Upvoted your answer

Comment: @AleksAndreev  Why not also update your answer to better match the requirement? I'm glad that someone else appreciates the .Net Regex object model--can be very useful and powerful.  `var pattern = new RX.Regex(@"(<(?<content>[^>]+)>){4}$");` and `var content = pattern.Match(source).Groups["content"].Captures.Cast<RX.Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: @Kyu96 Please clarify what you mean, which is exactly what you meant --  Aleks' answer or Matt's comment?  Your question shows precisely 4 occurances of <stuff>, so do you expect precise 4 or not?  Or did you intend to get something to match a less rigid number of occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if it's important that the match be anchored and have exactly 4 groups, then you will have to explicitly repeat the groups, which you could do like this:

```
^<(.+)><(.+)><(.+)><(.+)>$
```

although `[^>]` might be a safer bet than `.`

Then each piece of text between the brackets will be in a separate group in your match.

Obviously this isn't very flexible when you later decide you need to have 5 matches, or 50 matches or variable number of matches. In that case, use Aleks' answer.

Finally, if it's the case that your data is actually XML or something similar, you are probably better off not using regex at all and instead using an appropriate parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and it will work.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\w\s]+");

        string example = "<random stuff between><random stuff between>
                           <random stuff between><random stuff between><a><a 
                          a>";

        Match match = regex.Match(example);

        while (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```